# disable other default row- Entity framework

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table that name is `Store`  , In `Store` Table , just one row can `IsDefault=true` at time . when I insert new Row , I check If user selected IsDefault , I  update other row whice `isDefault=true` . I use this code :

```
public AddStatus Add(AddStoreViewModel storeViewModel)
    {
        if (Exists(storeViewModel.Name)) return AddStatus.Exists;
        var storeModel = Mapper.Map(storeViewModel, new StoreEntity.Store());
        if (storeModel.IsDefault)
        {
            var defaultStore = GetDefault();
            if (defaultStore != null)
            {
                defaultStore.IsDefault = false;
                _uow.MarkAsBaseChanged(defaultStore); // update
            }
        }
        _uow.MarkAsBaseAdded(storeModel);
        return AddStatus.Successfull;
    }
```

and in controller I call Above Method like belowe and Call SaveAllChanges :

```
 _storeService.Add(storeViewModel);
 await _uow.SaveChangesAsync();
```

and  MarkAsBaseChange like belowe :

```
  public void MarkAsBaseChanged<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : BaseEntity
    {
        Entry(entity).Entity.Action = Enums.AuditAction.Update;
}
```

is this code ok ?

Answer (score 1):

Does _uow.MarkAsBaseChanged() primarily hide EF's SaveChanges()?
If so, make a new version that can take an array of objeects.

You would want both objects saved with one command to ensure the transaction. As it ia nw, if storeModel fails you no longer have a default store.

Comment: pleas see new update

Comment: @Rahimi Then my answer stands. You have a hole in your logic if second save fails.

Comment: I dont call `SaveChanges` in `MarkAsBaseChanged` . In `MarkAsBaseChanged` I just Save some Log like `EditorIP` ,...